# Emailing with Attachments

Tags: php, email

Trying to accomplish this with just PHP and I'm at a snag where the HTML in the email is fine but the `boundary` sections appear as just normal text and the attachment wont attach.

```
$to = 'myemail@email.com';
$subject = 'Contact Submission';
$name       =   strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$emailto    =   strip_tags($_POST['emailto']);
$comments   =   strip_tags($_POST['comments']);
$attachment =   chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
$filename   =   $_FILES['file']['name'];

$boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: noreply@emailcom' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$comments="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        <table width=\"600px\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"style=\"\">
          <tr valign=\"top\">
            <th align=\"left\" style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px; padding-left:10px; line-height:32px\">Contact Submission</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br />

        <table width=\"600\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"style=\"border: 1px solid #000;\">
          <tr valign=\"top\">
            <td colspan=\"4\" style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;background:#ececec; line-height:32px;\" align=\"left\"><strong>Contact Information</strong></td>
        </tr>
          <tr valign=\"top\">
            <td style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; line-height:32px; font-weight:bold\" align=\"right\" width=\"120\">Name</td>
            <td style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; line-height:32px;padding-left:40px;\">$name</td>    
        </tr>
          <tr valign=\"top\">
            <td style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; line-height:32px; font-weight:bold; background:#e6edf2;\" align=\"right\" width=\"120\">Email</td>
            <td style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; line-height:32px;background:#e6edf2;padding-left:40px;\">$emailto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign=\"top\">
            <td style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; line-height:32px; font-weight:bold\" align=\"right\">Comments</td>
            <td style=\" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; line-height:32px;padding-left:40px;\" colspan=\"3\">$comments</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        --_2_$boundary--
        --_1_$boundary
        Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
        Content-Disposition: attachment 

        $attachment
        --_1_$boundary--";

                mail($to, $subject, $comments, $headers);
```

Any help would be great from anyone as to what needs changing/added/removed to get this email to keep my HTML table and also attach the file

Comment: @Spudley don't want to use PHPMailer if this can be achieved with the above code.

Comment: Download phpmailer or swiftmailer and look how they do it and alter your code accordingly.

Comment: Is boundary stored in $boundary $boundary-- $boundary\" ? try splitting variables from your strings http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (ie whats the generated output of $comments?)

Comment: @DonaldSutherland: I honestly can't understand why you would say that. phpMailer (or swiftmailer) is well written, secure, easy to use,  fully featured, and completely free. I can say with certainty that unless you're and expert already or willing to spend a lot of time, you're not going to be certain of your code being secure. It certainly isn't easy to use. And fully featured? All that code is just for regular attachments; if you ever want to add another feature (say HTML emails with inline graphics), it'll be another whole load of work. Ah well, your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$to = "email";
                    $subject = "your subject";
                    $base = basename($file1);
$file = fopen('file path','rb');
$size = filesize('file path');
$data = fread($file,$size);
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message="<html><body>";
$message="<table border='1'>";
$message.="<tr><td colspan='3' align='center' style='color:#FFFFFF;font-size:large; background:#000000'>Your Information</td></tr>";
$message.="<tr><td style='font-weight:bold'>field 1</td><td style='font-weight:bold'>field 2</td></tr>";
$message.="</table>";
$message.="</body></html>";

//boundary
$div = "==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(time())."x";
//headers
$head = "From: $email\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n".
    " boundary=\"$div\"";
//message
$mess = "--$div\n".
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".
    "$message\n\n".
    "--$div\n".
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$base\"\n".
    "Content-Description: $base\n".
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n".
    " filename=\"$base\"; size=$size;\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n".
    "$data\n\n".
    "--$div\n";
$return = "-f$email";

mail($to,$subject,$mess,$head,$return);
```

try this code